# Redux Observables: Custom observer with multiple events?

Tags: react-native, rxjs, phoenix-framework, redux-observable

Hi I'm trying to use redux-observables with react native and a websocket wrapper called Phoenix, which basically allows you to execute callbacks when certain messages are received through the websocket.

Here is the basic setup of what I'm trying to do:

```
import 'rxjs';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Socket, Channel } from 'phoenix';

import * as channelActions from '../ducks/channel';

export default function connectSocket(action$, store) {
  return action$.ofType(channelActions.SETUP)
    .mergeMap(action => {
      return new Observable(observer => {
        const socket = new Socket('http://localhost:4000/socket');

        const userId = store.getState().user.id;
        const channel = socket.channel(`user:${userId}`);

        channel
          .join()
          .receive('ok', response => observer.next({ type: 'join', payload: 'something' }))
          .receive('error', reason => observer.next({ type: 'error', payload: 'reason' }))

        channel.on('rooms:add', room => observer.next({ type: 'rooms:add', payload: '123' }))
        channel.on('something:else', room => observer.next({ type: 'something:else', payload: '123' }))
      });
    })
    .map(action => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'join':
          return channelActions.join(action.payload);
        case 'error':
          return channelActions.error(action.payload);
        case 'rooms:add':
          return channelActions.add(action.payload);
        case 'something:else':
          return channelActions.something(action.payload);
      }
    });
};
```

As you can see, there are several concerns / issues with this approach:

1. Different events are being fired from one observer. I don't know how to split them up besides that switch statement in the `.map()` function
2. I don't know where to call `observer.complete()` since I want it to continue to listen for all those events, not just once.
3. If I could extract the `channel` constant into a separate file available to several epics that would fix these concerns. However, `channel` is dependent on `socket`, which is dependent on `user`, which comes from the redux state.

So I'm quite confused on how to approach this problem. I think the ability to extract a global `channel` object would fix it, but that also depends on the user ID from the redux state. Any help is appreciated.

P.S. If it's worth anything, my use case is very similar to this guy (https://github.com/MichalZalecki/connect-rxjs-to-react/issues/1). One of the responders recommended using `Rx.Subject` but I don't know where to start with that...

Comment: More relevant to rxjs, consider adding rxjs, rx tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are making your life extra difficult. You have already mapped the events so why are you combining and remapping them? Map each event into its own stream and merge the results together.

```
// A little helper function to map your nonstandard receive
// function into its own stream
const receivePattern = (channel, signal, selector) => 
  Observable.fromEventPattern(
    h => channel.receive(signal, h),
    h => {/*However you unsubscribe*/},
    selector
  )

export default function connectSocket(action$, store) {
  return action$.ofType(channelActions.SETUP)
    // Observable.create is usually a crutch pattern
    // Use defer or using here instead as it is more semantic and handles
    // most of the stream lifecycle for you
    .mergeMap(action => Observable.defer(() => {
        const socket = new Socket('http://localhost:4000/socket');
        const userId = store.getState().user.id;
        const channel = socket.channel(`user:${userId}`);
        const joinedChannel = channel.join();

        // Convert the ok message into a channel join
        const ok = receivePattern(joinedChannel, 'ok')
          // Just an example of doing some arbitrary mapping since you seem to be doing it 
          // in your example
          .mapTo('something')
          .map(channelActions.join);

        // Convert the error message
        const error = receivePattern(joinedChannel, 'error')
          .map(channelActions.error);

        // Since the listener methods follow a standard event emitter interface
        // You can use fromEvent to capture them
        // Rather than the more verbose fromEventPattern we used above
        const addRooms = Observable.fromEvent(channel, 'rooms:add')
          .map(channelActions.add);

        const somethingElse = Observable.fromEvent(channel, 'something:else')
          .map(channelActions.somethingElse);

        // Merge the resulting stream into one
        return Observable.merge(ok, error, addRooms, somethingElse);
      });
  );
};
```